# Is it possible to create an r conda environment from an existing version of r?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, conda

I had R 3.6 installed on my computer a long time ago and it has all of the packages that I typically use. I wanted to make a jupyter notebook using this version of R, however my R conda environment is a different version of r and has none of my typical packages. Is there a way to create a new R conda environment from my non-conda version of R? And/or, is there still a way I can use my preferred non-conda version of R as a kernel in Jupyter Notebooks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a non-Conda version of R cannot be used as a basis for a Conda environment.

However, it is possible to use any R installation as a kernel in Jupyter, no matter where either are installed. The key to doing so is to install IRkernel package in the R environment.

## Steps for Registering R as a Jupyter Kernel

0. If the Jupyter is installed in a Conda env, e.g., `my_jupyter_env`, first activate that env:

   ```
   $ conda activate my_jupyter_env
   (my_jupyter_env) $
   ```

   Otherwise, i.e., `jupyter` is on `PATH`, then just continue without any Conda envs activated.
1. Start an R session using the native R:

   ```
   (my_jypyter_env) $ path/to/native/R
   ```
2. Install `IRkernel`:

   ```
   > install.packages("IRkernel")
   ```

   Note that if this R is in a Conda env, instead use `conda install r-irkernel` outside of the R session.
3. From the R session, register R as a kernel. For example, if I had an R 3.6.0 natively installed I might call it:

   ```
   > IRkernel::installspec(name="ir36_native", displayname="R 3.6.0 (native)")
   ```

   but the arguments are whatever you want.
4. Quit the session and start Jupyter.

   ```
   > q()
   (my_jupyter_env) $ jupyter notebook
   ```
5. Use the "**New**" button to create a new notebook and select the R kernel from the dropdown.

Comment: This answer is underrated and helped me solve this problem that messed up my workflow for over a year

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can run `conda search r-base` which in my case returns

```
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
r-base                         3.1.2               0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.1.3               0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.1.3               1  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.1.3               2  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.2.0               0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.2.1               0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.2.2               0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.3.1               1  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.3.1               2  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.3.1               3  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.3.1               5  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.3.1               6  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.3.2               0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.3.2               1  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.4.1               0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.4.1               1  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.4.2      haf99962_0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.4.3      h1c2f66e_4  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.4.3      h1e0a451_2  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.4.3      h290ecf8_0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.4.3      h290ecf8_1  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.4.3      h9bb98a2_5  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.5.0      h1c2f66e_1  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.5.0      h1e0a451_1  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.5.1      h1e0a451_2  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.5.3      h067a564_0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.5.3      h26b83e4_0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.6.0      hce969dd_0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.6.1      h9bb98a2_1  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.6.1      haffb61f_2  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.6.1      hce969dd_0  pkgs/r
```

and you install your favorite version with `conda install r-base=x.x.x`

Comment: thanks for the info. It looks like when I try to run conda install r-base= 3.6.1, it asks whether I want to download packages. However, these don't seem to match all of the packages that I already have in my other version of 3.6.1. It sounds like I have to manually install all of the extra packages I have installed on my non-conda version?

Comment: In this case you are installing a new version of conda on a given environment. You should install all the other packages. I strongly recommend to don't mix with conda and os version of R. It's a pain to maintain and it's very hard to have a reproducible env.