# Change R version of the shell on Mac

Tags: r, macos, shell, conda, rscript

my R version on the zsh shell is the 3.6 that is different respect to the one of RStudio that is the 4. In fact, using the Jupyter notebook, the R version is the one used by conda. In fact, to install an r package I must run `conda install -c r r-package_name`. So, this is very annoying. How can I link the R version of Rscript of the shell with the one of the Rstudio?

Comment: Oops. Think I misread the question at first. You want to access the system- or user-level R installation from shell. Have you tried deactivating the Conda environment (`conda deactivate`) before running your script? That should restore the default precedents, assuming you are not manually adding Conda's `bin/` to PATH.

Comment: @merv I want to use just one versione of R, the one used by R studio. I should link this R version with conda; because it is manage the notebook on Mac

Comment: You mean like this?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63210058/570918