# Reinstall r packages? Shifting to using conda

Tags: r, anaconda, conda, rstudio

I'm running R on jupyterlab for the first time, so I had to start using anaconda/miniconda. When I started running a notebook that called a library (tidyverse) I'm certain I've already installed before on my RStudio (not installed via conda), it said there's no package called 'tidyverse'.

Is there a way I can make conda know I already have these packages? or will I need to reinstall everything on conda?

Right now, I'm only re-installing the packages that I need for my project, which is not optimal as it creates redundancies in my system.

Comment: In general you _cannot_ mix Conda and your normal installation as they use different system level libraries and compilers. So it either 'everything conda' or none.  You should be able to use use Jupyterlab on top of a standard installation.

Comment: I had to use conda because the standard R installation couldn't find jupyter. (maybe because I initially installed jupyterlab via pip?)

Comment: Not sure why would R want to find jupyter, perhaps you mean some other package? If I'm not mistaking, the Python environment only works on Python packages. If you want something that will work on everything, you could perhaps try Docker or Nix. But this is a more engineering heavy approach and may not be for everyone.

Comment: Sounds a lot like this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/63196684/570918. Otherwise, for Conda R, there are details in this answer (use Conda Forge): https://stackoverflow.com/a/69921221/570918